# Will an iterator cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, iterator

Will this cause a memory leak if I don't delete the *itr? I'm just wondering for a project and don't want to have points taken off.

```
void Directory::removeFile(string fName)
{
// Get files from directory
list<Folder> folders = this->getFolders();
list<File> files = this->getFiles();
for (list<Folder>::iterator itr = folders.begin(); itr != folders.end(); ++itr)
{
    if (fName == (*itr).getFolderName())
    {
        cout << fName << ": Is a directory." << endl;
        return;
    }
}
for (list<File>::iterator itr = files.begin(); itr != files.end(); ++itr)
{
    if (fName == (*itr).getFileName())
    {
        cout << "Found it" << endl;
        itr = files.erase(itr);
        this->setFiles(files);
        return;
    }
} 
cout << "This file does not exist." << endl;
}
```

Edit: The reason why I am asking this is because I did valgrind and got this as a result. Is this a memory leak?

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==27219==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27219==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 25 frees, 82,671 bytes allocated
==27219==
==27219== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27219==
==27219== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==27219== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I don't see a `new` or even a pointer, so probably not. But it might if `File` is susceptible of leaking. Why do you suspect it would leak? Understanding that would help us answer your quesiton.

Comment: Memory leaks come from allocations that aren't properly reclaimed. What are you allocating in here? Can you step through in a debugger and find out more?

Comment: Iterators, as a concept, are not a memory leak risk. Though there's no telling what problems a sufficiently poor implementation can have.

Comment: The only potential source of a memory leak here would be if the `Folder` and `File` types don't free their resources

Comment: I'll take a snippet when I get home. But I did a valgrind and it had like a heap amount of 56k or something like that. I don't really remember what exactly was said. I don't use valgrind too often.

Comment: Off topic: You *copy* your lists of files and folders, modify them and then copy them back (`setFiles`). You can spare all this if your getters return references and you assign to those as well...

Comment: I added a snippet of the result from valgrind. That's what made me ask this question.

Comment: @JakeYoung "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible" is quite clear, isn't it?

Comment: I just wasn't sure why that 82k bytes allocated was so high. I thought that might have been something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to `delete` a `list<Folder>::iterator itr` since it is a variable with automatic storage duration that is not a pointer.

Please remember that you only may feed pointers that you obtained using `new` to `delete` and pointers obtained using `new[]` to `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this cause a memory leak if I don't delete the *itr?

No, it won't.

`std::list::erase` will make sure that the destructor of the object contained at the location, in your case a `File` object, will be called.